# Sails.Js - Simple Exercise with 2 Relations on the ORM

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm, sails.js

I'm new to Sails.js and Node.js, so if i'm asking a simple question please forgive me.

I'm doing an API that must have a database, and i wanted to implement MySQL because i have some relations between tables. So i wrote the relational model by hand, like it is on the figure:

[image]

And i tried to implement is using sails.js, but for some reason i can't get the relation Level to Score working while the User-Score relationship is working fine.

Here are my models:

### User.JS

```js
module.exports = {



  attributes: {



      name:{
        type:'string',
        required: true
      },

      address:{
        type: 'string'
      },

      email:{
        type: 'string',
        email:true,
        unique: true,
        required: true
      },
      encryptedPassword:{
        type: 'string'
      },

      tranusertoscore:{
        collection:'scores',
        via: 'transcoretouser'
      }

    }
  }
```

### Level.js

```js
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    lvl_name:{
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },



    tranleveltoscore:{
      collection: 'scores',
      via: 'transcoretolevels'
    }

  }
};
```

and finally

### Score.js

```js
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    lvl:{
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },

    score:{
      type: 'integer',
      required: true
    },

    transcoretouser:{
      model: 'user'
    },

    transcoretolevels:{
      model: 'level'
    }
  }
};
```

So, can you guys tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Sorry to take your time if the answer is easy, but i tried to follow documentation and search about the subject and didn't find any relevant answers.

Comment: What doesn't work with the association?

Comment: When you go see a score....it doesn't say his lvl_name, but he shows the user. What can it be?

Comment: Do you use `populate`? http://sailsjs.org/#!/documentation/reference/waterline/queries/populate.html

Comment: Yes, maybe i'm not using it correcly....i'll post the populate code here.

Comment: @Yann Bertrand So what i do is something in the lines of this...
 `//Create a Level 
Level.create({lvl_name:'Palavra a Palavra' }).exec(function levelCreated(err,lvl){
              if(err) console.log(err);
            }); `

and then 

`Scores.create({lvl:'pap1', score:0, transcoretouser:user.id, transcoretolevels:parseInt(lvlid1)}).exec(function scoreCreated(err,scr) {
            if (err) return err;
          });`

The populate i only use to find scores.